# Trouble with three movieclips AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have little problem,

Namely, I have been created three MovieClips

I gave for each MC linkage A1, A2, A3.

On stage I placed code:

```
var a1:A1 = new A1();
var a2:A2 = new A2();

addChild(a1);
a1.addChild(a2);
```

in A2 I wrote:

```
var a3:A3 = new A3();
addChild(a3);
trace(a3.t);
```

and in A3 I placed:

```
var t:String = "test";
```

Trace returns me "null" why ?

Comment: When you say "In A2" and "In A3", did you actually make .as files for these classes or did you just place that code into the movieclip's timeline?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say for sure without knowing what your class files look like or where exactly you put that line declaring and assigning a value to  t.

Is t a property of the A3 Class ?

Meaning you have it in your property declarations in that class :

```
public var t:String = "test";
```

If not, you are dealing with a scope issue as t has no scope outside where you declared it.

For example if you have this line in your constructor :

```
var t:String = "test";
```

It's scope is limited to your constructor.

What you need to do is make t a public property of your A3 class.

This is an example :

```
package
{
     public class A3 extends MovieClip
     {
         // declare as class property
         public var t:String;

         public function A3()
         {
              // assign value to class property t
              t = "Test";
         }

         public function doSomething():void
         {
              // this local variable is not accessible outside this function
              var someVariable:String = "test";
         }


     }
}
```

As pointed out by a commenter, if you choose not to declare a property as public/private, it defaults to private and therefore not visible outside of the class. You cannot declare a variable as public/private within a method. Any variables declared inside a method are scoped to that method - local variables - and are only accessible within that method.

Comment: var t without a public scope is never going to be available outside the instance (except in some cases by an instance of the exact same Class).

Comment: Which is why I said "t's scope is limited to your constructor.", after that line.

Comment: Even if it's not in the constructor, the scope won't be visible outside the instance.

Comment: I was giving an example of scope. If it's declared where I specified, it's accessible outside of the class. But yes, you are correct that if it's a local variable to ANY method in that class, it's not accessible outside of the instance.  I'll ad that for clarity.

Comment: Even outside a method, if you don't declare it public, it's not public.

Comment: You've completely lost me, please look at the bottom of my answer where I give the correct usage --- I declare it as public. So, not sure what you are having trouble understanding of feeling is incorrect about that.

Comment: I'm not having trouble understanding your answer (but I get the feeling you don't understand that the default namespace for variable declarations in the Class scope but not within a method is private). I was agreeing with your answer and expanding on it. This was sparked by your statement that without seeing the Class code you couldn't say for sure. That statement is always going to be local or private, and hence not visible outside the Class, no matter where in the Class it is--local inside a method and private outside.

Comment: Now I understand what you are getting at. I didn't cover defaults. I was just pointing out the line that was incorrect and then gave correct usage. That is correct, if you don't specify, it defaults to private and his line if anywhere in the class would default to private.

Comment: I will modify the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Modified to reflect that detail, sorry for the misunderstanding. You are correct, that it's very likely that he has the declaration in the right location, but it's simply not specified as public. I thought that giving a full example at the end would cover it well enough for him to be fine.